# How to identify specific cell in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

[image]

I want set color **black color** for **cell1,cell4,cell7 ,...n**  &  **white color** for **cell2,cell5,cell8 ,...n**
**Note: Number of cell are not fixed.**

How can I implement this??

Comment: Are they static cells?

Comment: No , All cells are dynamic

Comment: So, you want to change background color for odd and even cell. am I right?

Comment: No, I do not want to change odd even cell. Please read my question again

Comment: Is there any data for that you want to change the color of background?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala Cell contain just 1 label and 1 imageview

Comment: You want like something black color for left side and white color for right side. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes @NiravDoctorwala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` knows how to get cell number (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` on your picture) from `NSIndexPath` passed to the method. Then you can decide on what color to use by obtaining a remainder of division by 3, like this:

```
// Decode index path into cell number from your picture
int cellNumber = [self getCellNumberFromIndexPath:indexPath];
// Figure out the color
if (cellNumber % 3 == 1) {
    // 1, 4, 7, etc
    ... // Use black color
} else if (cellNumber % 3 == 2) {
    // 2, 5, 8, etc
    ... // Use white color
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working

Answer (score 1):

Just as you would have done for odd/even (using n % 2 == 0|1) condition.

Here, you want it for every third cell. So, you can modify the logic of odd/even by using 3 instead of 2.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // .... YOUR CURRENT CODE

    // Color change as you wanted it.,,

    if (YOUR_CELL_INDEX % 3 == 0) {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else { YOUR_CELL_INDEX % 3 == 1) {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {
         cell.backgroundColor = // Your choice of color....
    }

    // .... REST OF YOUR CODE & return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add as

```
 if indexPath.item % 3 == 0
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        }
        else if indexPath.item % 3 == 1{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.WhiteColor()

        }
```

Comment: this answer is for perticular cell item for Custom Cell